# How to override schema use on ibm_db.exec_immediate(connect, sql) in Python

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to run a run `select count(*) from 'ActualSchemaUser.TABLE_NAME' where 'DATE_CREATE' >= 2019-10-17` and I get the following error:

**
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXZ64] SQL0204N  "DatabaseUSer.ActualSchemaUser.TABLE_NAME" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704 SQLCODE=-204
**

It looks like `ibm_db.exec_immediate(connect, sql)` adds the database connecting user to the query from ibm_db module perspective.

Is there a way I can prevent set or override the schema for **ibm_db.exec_immediate()** function.

Python code snippet:

```
import ibm_db
connect  = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=DatabaseName;HOSTNAME=DatabaseHostname;PORT=DatabaseName;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=DatabaseUSer; PWD=DataBasePassword;", "", "")

schemaName = 'ActualSchemaUser'
sql = "select count(*) from '{}.TABLE_NAME' where 'DATE_CREATE' >= 2019-10-17".format(schemaName)
statement = ibm_db.exec_immediate(connect, sql)
result = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(statement)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote separately schema and table name:

```
schemaName = 'ActualSchemaUser'
sql = "select count(*) from \"{}\".\"TABLE_NAME\" where DATE_CREATE >= 2019-10-17".format(schemaName)
# or sql = 'select count(*) from "{}"."TABLE_NAME" where DATE_CREATE >= 2019-10-17'.format(schemaName)
statement = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
result = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(statement)

Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  "ActualSchemaUser.TABLE_NAME" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704 SQLCODE=-204
```

(of course I don't the the table)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it is a Python issue, but wrong quoting around [SQL identifiers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000720.html). You need to use

```
select count(*) from "ActualSchemaUser"."TABLE_NAME"
where 'DATE_CREATE' >= 2019-10-17
```

There should be double quotes for SQL identifiers, single quotes for string values. The two part name consists of the schema and the table name and both a separate identifiers.

Comment: I just realized I did not separate the schema and the table as you did on your comment "ActualSchemaUser"."TABLE_NAME"